# How to subtract two time difference rows in the same column (like A2-A1) but in PowerBI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

Hello PowerBI (DAX) lovers,

I cant find suitable DAX function which will help me to calculate (subtract) two different time periods, so A2-A1 would be Excel like and so on. In Excel it is easier with MOD function, I am familiar with that, and works good. But, thing is, I would like to do all the stuff of my analytics in PowerBI, not partly Excel (like this) and then I have to upload xlsx. files and work with them.

I was looking for some examples but none of them was good enough to calculate this. The only thing I did now is inserting Index column which might be starting point..but I am looking for your experience?

This is the data set that I isolate part per part, and the column that I would like to solve is **Time column** , where I wanna subtract second number against first (17:00 - 13:00 and so on..) accordingly.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: You may want to do your data cleaning with the Query editor instead of DAX functions. That way you don't have to carry the original Value column around forever.

Comment: Thank you. But my data set is a bit "strange" lets say so, and in PQ Editor wasnt possible to extract all the stuff. But I managed it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the suggest and help of user @Alexis Olson I managed to extend and to solve my small problem: This was DAX that I used in calculated column:

```
TimeDiff = 'Explog2019-08-07'[Time] 
- LOOKUPVALUE('Explog2019-08-07'[Time];'Explog2019-08-07'[Index];
        'Explog2019-08-07'[Index]+1)
```

So it was possible to solve it without connecting date+time as previously suggested.

[image]

Comment: I would have thought you'd have issues with just time when you're doing subtraction across days but maybe the time format is smart enough to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated column that combines `Date` and `Time` so you can subtract across days. Let's call it `DateTime`.

Then your calculated column for the difference will look something like

```
TimeDiff =
ExpLog[DateTime]
    - MAXX (
        FILTER ( ExpLog, ExpLog[Index] < EARLIER ( [ExpLog[Index] ) ),
        ExpLog[DateTime]
    )
```

Instead of `MAXX`, you could probably use a lookup instead

```
TimeDiff =
ExpLog[DateTime] - LOOKUPVALUE ( ExpLog[DateTime], ExpLog[Index], ExpLog[Index] - 1 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Well, it is partly correct, I got the Time difference with minor change in your coding - I used Lookup version and put +1 instead of -1, which is exactly how I did and got in Excel. But the Date in front is quite wrong , actually repetitive through whole data set: 30.12.1899 

So I just Changed Data type in Modeling tab into Time and got my stuff! 

Thank you one more time!

Comment: And one more thing! I just managed it using your coding but without making extra column actually...it is enough with this: TimeDiff = 'Explog2019-08-07'[Time] - LOOKUPVALUE('Explog2019-08-07'[Time];'Explog2019-08-07'[Index];'Explog2019-08-07'[Index]+1)